# Data constructors and universe constraints

Tags: agda

In the code below:

```
data Foo₁ : Set where
  foo₁ : Set → Foo₁

data Foo₂ (A : Set) : Set where
  foo₂ : Foo₂ A

type₂ : {A : Set} → Foo₂ A
type₂ = foo₂
```

for the constructor `foo₁` I get this error message:

```
Set₁ is not less or equal than Set when checking that the type Set → Foo₁ of the constructor foo₁ fits in the sort Set of the datatype.
```

I don't see the difference between the "1" and "2" versions of `foo`, though.  Why am I not seeing the same error for `foo₂`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

foo₁ gives a type error because the type of constructors* should live in the same type as that of the inductive type. That is, Foo₁ is declared to live in Set₀, while the constructor's type Set₀ → Foo₁ lives in Set₁ because Set₀ lives in Set₁, and that's larger than Set₀ as declared.

On the other hand, inductive types are *a little* impredicative wrt their parameters. This means that parameters can live in the same universe as the inductive type itself, and you can write something well typed like (Foo₂ (Foo₂ A)) given some A in Set₀.

The *difference*, meanwhile, is that as a parameter, you can't really "hide" a type inside of the inductive: when you declare a (Foo₂ A), you have to give that A up front. On the other hand, (foo₁ A) of type Foo₁ in Set₀ "hides" the type A of type Set₀ in Set₁, which means given some Foo₁, you're able to extract something in a universe "hidden" in the inductive.

```
extract : Foo₁ → Set₀
extract (foo₁ A) = A
```

So a constructor like foo₁ is disallowed because you would otherwise be able to pretend that a larger universe is actually a smaller one by hiding it inside a Foo₁, which usually leads to inconsistencies. Although I'm not sure if it actually does in the specific case of Foo₁.

---

*Clarification: I mentioned this in a comment but I mean the type of constructors *under the context of the parameters*. So in general, given some inductive definition (ignore indices for now)

```
data I (p₁: A₁) ... (pₙ: Aₙ): Setⱼ where
  ...
  cᵢ: C
  ...
```

the constructor's type has to satisfy (among other things) the judgement

```
p₁: A₁, ..., pₙ: Aₙ, I: (p₁: A₁) → ... (pₙ: Aₙ) → Setⱼ ⊢ C : Setⱼ
```

Comment: It seems to me that `Foo₁` is basically asserting that `Set` contains a copy of itself, which is surely inconsistent by the usual sort of arguments.

Comment: But to my question, doesn't the type of the `foo₂` constructor also live in `Set₁`?  So why does agda think that one is OK?

Comment: The types of constructors have to live in the inductive type's universe under the context of the parameters, I suppose you could say. If you have `data I (p: A): Setᵢ where c: B` then the requirement is that `p: A, I p: Setᵢ ⊢ B: Setᵢ`, in short, and that's the condition on inductives that Agda checks. Moving the parameter to the other side of the turnstile (e.g. going from `foo₂` to `foo₁`) like `(p: A) → B` might not be well typed in `Setᵢ` if `A` is too big. But yeah, on its own I guess `foo₂` also has type `(A: Set₀) → Foo A` which is in `Set₁`.

Answer (score 4):

Let us read the definitions set-theoretically.

The constructor `foo₁` is an inclusion `Set → Foo₁`, therefore `Foo₁` is at least as large as `Set`, but on the other hand `Foo₁ : Set`, and so we have a size problem.

The map `Foo₂ : Set → Set` takes a set `A` and yields a set `Foo₂ A`, which has just one element, namely `foo₂`. The constructor `foo₂` is a choice map: for each set `A` it returns the only element of `Foo₂ A`.

Without all the fancy Agda notation the above two examples would be written by a mathematician somewhat like this:

1. We cannot have a set $S \in \mathsf{Set}$ and an inclusion $i : \mathsf{Set} \to S$. (Translation: $S$ is `Foo₁` and $i$ is `foo₁`.)
2. For a set $A$, let $S_A = \{ \star_A \}$. (Translation: $S_A$ is `Foo₂ A` and `foo₂` is the map $A \mapsto \star_A$.)

In the second example, we could take a concrete encoding of $\star_A$, such as $\star_A = \{A\}$ or $\star = \{\}$. In any case, there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Is there a difference between an "inclusion" and an "injection"?  I guess constructors are injective by definition?

Anyway, nice interpretation, thanks.

Comment: The terminology varies. Injection often means "injective function", whereas "inclusion" might mean something more specific, such as an inclusion of a subset into its superset (which is the sense in which I used inclusion). But "injection" is also used in specific cases, for example an injection `inl : A → A + B`. I used "inclusion" to indicate that `foo₁` is more like a subset inclusion, but the difference is not essential.